# ASP.Net MVC 5 Routing wildcard + querystring

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using this Route filter

```
[Route("search/{*segments}")]
```

this takes all the segments I am providing which could be many.

Here is an example

```
http://localhost:50877/search/c_50_showcases%5E-displays/a_brand-name:33113319_balt:1623762%7Cmooreco:1672386/a_total-number-of-shelves:33111115429_5:3138:lt/so_ts
```

Now I also need the query string with this route but I am unable to make it work.

```
http://localhost:50877/search/?query=HP%20DesignJet&items=HEW51645A|ELI75220
```

It gives me `403` error.

> The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory

How can I make a route that can take wildcard and query string to handle the incoming request. I am bound to use `search` in `Route`.

Also I tried with this

```
http://localhost:50877/search/test?query=HP%20DesignJet&items=HEW51645A|ELI75220
```

It works but this effects the SEO.

Comment: See [The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32143133/181087)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining action and route this way:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Route("search/{*segments}")]
public ActionResult Search(string segments, string query, string items)
```

allows to get wildcard (in segments variable) and also query string parameters (query and items)