# Returning a 404 when the URL does not contain Index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having trouble with routing in  MVC. I have created a controller for my contact page, but unless I specify the route as `/contact/index` it will return a 404. I cannot see why it can't find the View with just `/contact` in the URL. My `RouteConfig` looks fine to me.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "T",
                url: "T/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Holding",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Holding", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

The only reason I can see it not finding its View is because of the new Route I have configured to display a site holding page. Interestingly `/t` does display the 'demo' homepage, so I can't see why it doesn't like just `/contact`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139035/asp-net-mvc-routes-how-do-i-omit-index-from-a-url) S.O article told me that I could fix the problem by giving it its own `MapRoute` but I shouldn't have to do all that?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
        return View();
     }

     public ActionResult Holding()
     {
         return View();
     }
}

public class ContactController : Controller
{
    // GET: Contact
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

It must be something silly, but I can't work it out.

Comment: You have route conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have route conflicts

`/contact` would match

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Holding",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Holding", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But since contact controller has no `Holding` action you will get a *404 Not Found*

And since it matched the *Holding* route it wont go on to the next *Default* route as first match wins.

The added route is too general so it will get a lot of false matches.

Based on the controllers shown, the added route is not needed. the holding path would still match the default route template. So it can actually be removed altogether.

Comment: I see, thanks very much, I will need to look at redirecting, rather than setting up a Route and creating conflicts :-)